# how to mix a normal server website and a pwa?

Tags: blazor, progressive-web-apps, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Is that possible to run it as a server website and show an install button when visiting, just like GitHub did?

[image]

I created a website by Microsoft Blazor web assembly PWA, but the website loads slowly at first time visiting. I am expecting it can run as a server hosting website and alternative way to install as a progressive web application.